# How can alter the select options provided by Simple hierarchical select?

Tags: 8, forms

[Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) is used to display Taxonomy as a select field in my existing content type. So I'm trying to alter the value of it. Even tried using `hook_form_alter` but didn't work. So is there any way or hook using which I can alter the value of the select list?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Yes, that hook would be `hook_form_alter`. Maybe you can paste the code that didn't work so we may have a look at it. Maybe you have to ensure your `hook_form_alter` implementation runs last (after `shs`) via [`hook_module_implements_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7.x). Hard to tell with that little info.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I was able to resolve it by using the module handler "shs_term_data_response". Like below

```
function YourModuleName_shs_term_data_response_alter(&$content, $context) {
  $termList = json_decode($content);
  $filteredList = array();
  /..your logic to modify $termList and push it to new array.../
  $content = json_encode($filteredList);
}
```

Hope it may help someone :)